# Align caret with dotted bottom border in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to align a caret with a dotted bottom border.

I managed to achieve it using [this code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEVzOx) but it works only in Chromium.

HTML:

```
<h2 id="a11y-291">
  More <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle h2Title" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="dashedUnderline">albums</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" role="button">artists</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#" role="button">albums</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</h2>
```

and css:

```
.noMarginTop {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.h2Title {
    border: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.h2Title:active,
.h2Title:hover,
.h2Title:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.caret {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1em;  // Not aligned in FF
}

.h2Title .caret {
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.dashedUnderline {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

It works as expected in Chromium:

[image: Chromium]

But there is a slight offset in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Has anyone a more reliable way to achieve this? I cannot figure out what differs between Firefox and Chromium resulting in an offset.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the issue is the Caret?  When I overlay your two example images the caret is positioned in the same space.  The issue seems to be that Firefox is spacing the underline effect lower than Chromium.

Comment: Robert is right. Though, I just tested your codepen example in both browsers on my comp., and both look identical. Caret and the dotted line are aligned the same.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Do you know a way to fix this? I did not find anything to make the border closer to content, and my elements have zero padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.noMarginTop {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.h2Title {
    border: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.h2Title:active,
.h2Title:hover,
.h2Title:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.h2Title .caret {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
/* you must add display:inline-block to.dashedUnderline and .caret */
.dashedUnderline, .caret {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.caret {
    margin-top: 29px; 
}
.dashedUnderline {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
       <h2 id="a11y-291">
  More 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle h2Title" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="dashedUnderline">albums</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" role="button">artists</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#" role="button">albums</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
    </h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! (note that you miss the button styling in your snippet), but just adding `.dashedUnderline, .caret {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}` works fine!)